# I have JSON from server like this:

Tags: typescript

```
[
  {
    "id":"one",
    "state":"two",
    "url":"www.google.com",
    "childs":[
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":"two",
    "state":"three",
    "url":"www.yahoo.com",
    "childs":[
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four"
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to convert this JSON to

```
[  
              {  
                "name":"id",
                "children":[  
                    {  
                      "name":"one"
                    }
                ]
              },
              {  
                "name":"state",
                "children":[  
                    {  
                      "name":"two"
                    }
                ]
              },
              {  
                "name":"url",
                "children":[  
                    {  
                      "name":"www.google.com"
                    }
                ]
              },
              {  
                "name":"childs",
                "children":[  
                    {  
                      "name":"one"
                    },
                    {  
                      "name":"two"
                    },
                    {  
                      "name":"three"
                    },
                    {  
                      "name":"four"
                    }
                ]
              }

          ]
```

I am using JS to get this as below:

```
buildChildrenNodes() {
    let arrayOneStrings: Array<object> = [];
    this.treedata.map((element: any) => {
        const sortedData = Object.entries(element);
        let arrayTwoStrings: Array<object> = [];
        for (const [key, value] of sortedData) {
            const twoElement =
            {
                name: key,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: value
                    }
                ]
            }
            arrayTwoStrings.push(twoElement);
        }
        const oneElement = {
            name: element.id,
            children: arrayTwoStrings
        };
        arrayOneStrings.push(oneElement);
    });
    this.formattedTreeData = arrayOneStrings;
};
```

Can Anyone suggest me how we could loop through sub childrens? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you should be able to loop through children by nesting these loops

Comment: Could your data also be more deeply nested?  For instance, could your object also contain properties whose values are also objects?  Or will you only have strings and arrays of strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

- Object.entries gives key and values of each element on arr.
- map through each entry and check whether the value is string or array. add children accordingly.
- Push the values to `op`

```js
let arr = [{"id":"one","state":"two","url":"www.google.com","childs":["one","two","three","four"]},{"id":"two","state":"three","url":"www.yahoo.com","childs":["one","two","three","four"]}]

let op = arr.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let temp = Object.entries(inp).map(([key,value]) => ({name:key, children:Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(e=>({name:e})) : ([{name:value}])}))
  op.push(...temp)
  return op
},[])

console.log(op)
```

Comment: @Vicky always happy to help :) you can mark it as correct answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

This function should run on content nested arbitrarily deep:

```js
const is = (T) => (val) => val != null && val.constructor === T || val instanceof T;

const transform = (x) => 
  is (Array) (x)
    ? x .map (transform)
    : is (Object) (x)
      ? Object .entries (x) .map (
          ([name, val]) => ({
            name, 
            children: transform(val)
          })
        )
      : {name: x}



const data = [{id: "one", state: "two", url: "www.google.com", childs: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]}, {id: "two", state: "three", foo: {bar: "baz", quz: "corg"}, url :"www.yahoo.com", childs: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]}]

console.log(transform(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper: {height: 100% !important}
```

Note that I added a deeper node on the second value, `foo: {bar: 'baz', quz: 'corg'}`, and that just continues a little deeper in the output:

```
    {
      name: "foo",
      children: [
        {
          name: "bar",
          children: {
            name: "baz"
          }
        },
        {
          name: "quz",
          children: {
            name: "corg"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

The `is` function is [borrowed from Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/is.js#L27-L29).  It simply tests whether a value is a given type.  If desired, we could cache `is (Array)` and `is (Object)` as `isArray` and `isObject` and replace those calls.